# apa-good.bst question

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I'm very unfamiliar with `.bst` files.  I'm not using BibLatex yet, just standard BibTex.  If I want the `apa-good.bst` to work with my thesis, do I have to also have the `apa.cls` in the same directory?  I apologize up front for the newbie question.

Comment: No.  (Did you try it?) :)

Comment: @AlanMunn Honestly, I don't know whats going on... when I try to compile the thesis Bibtex I get 3087 errors (literally) so I'm just trying to find out what I needed to get it to run the apa format.

Comment: Before working with your thesis, try a simple small document with one or two citations, `natbib` and no other packages loaded. Does that work?  What kind of errors are you getting, and when? (During the latex compilation or the bibtex compilation?)

Comment: @AlanMunn I managed to muscle my way through it. Thanks Alan.